# HowTo map Javers snapshot to entity via JPA annotations/converter

Tags: java, spring, jpa, converters, javers

Given code:

```
public enum ApplicationStatus {
     CREATED, VERIFIED, APPROVED, REJECTED, DELETED, PUBLISHED;
}

@lombok.Data // adds constructors, getters, setters, equals & hashcode
@Table("Application")
public class Application implements Serializable {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ApplicationStatus status;

    @Transient
    @Converter(HistoryConverter.class)
    private List<Application> applicationHistory;
}

@Repository
@JaversSpringDataAuditable
public interface ApplicationRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Application, Long> {}

@Component
@Converter
public class HistoryConverter implements AttributeConverter<Application, List<Application>> {

    @Autowired
    private Javers javers;

    @Override
    public List<Application> convertToDatabaseColumn(Application entity) {
        List<CdoSnapshot> snapshots = javers.findSnapshots(QueryBuilder.byInstanceId(entity.getId(), Application.class).build())

        return snapshots.stream().map(s -> convertToEntity(s.getState())).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private Application convertToEntity(CdoSnapshot snapshot) {
        JsonConverter gson = javers.getJsonConverter();
        String json = gson.toJson(state);
        return gson.fromJson(json, Application.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Application convertToEntityAttribute(List<Application> dbData) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

How to make JPA use my converter to convert snapshot got from javers back to Application entity object for list of history objects?

I didn't find what I'm looking for on google. Only a thread saying that it will be possible in the future to get object from snapshot. For such simple object I'm using it can be done as presented above. But how it can be incorporated into the code so snapshots can be used as history entry.

Javers store new snapshot for every saved change of the entity into database in its own table. State field/column is encoded to json by Gson (internally). So using Gson to convert it back to entity can be done as follows. This concept works but not automatically. Can you please help me in incorporating javers as out-of-the-box history mechanism into my code?

Of course changes to entity class as well as converter class are welcome but history has to be done by javers snapshots instead of reinventing the wheel by introducing new entity with history state and process it as seperate entity.

Comment: An AttributeConverter is to convert from a field value to a datastore value. The field is transient therefore there is no concept of datastore value, hence it won't be used.

Comment: @NeilStockton: Like I said, you can propose the change of given code. I am aware that in its current state it doesn't work but that's the whole point of this forum to help give answers.

Comment: I'm simply explaining WHY it doesn't work. I would have thought that adds to your knowledge ...

Comment: @NeilStockton: Well in that case please do accept my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Restoring original domain objects from CdoSnapshots is not yet implemented in JaVers. There are some plans about this - https://github.com/javers/javers/issues/133

Comment: I already have my converter which will convert snapshots to domain objects but I just need a way to execute it. The question is just how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Restore orginal domain object from persisted snapshot](https://github.com/javers/javers/issues/133#issuecomment-304259072) issue mentioned by @Bartek, this feature has been implemented in version 3.2.0, back in 2017.

In JaVers, the feature is called Shadow, meaning users domain object restored from a Snapshot.

More information in the [Querying for Shadows section of the JQL (JaVers Query Language) examples official documentation page](https://javers.org/documentation/jql-examples/#query-for-shadows).